# java: method correctOutOf in class littleQuiz cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, methods

My goal is to store the amount of correct answers into the 'correctOutOf' method, which will then return the value of corrAns when called int the `/*Wrapping Up*/` section of the example code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class littleQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

        char yesno;
        int answer;

        /*Welcome/Splash Screen*/
        /*Ask if ready and accept yes or no with appropriate return response*/
        System.out.print("Are you ready for a quiz? Y or N ");
        yesno = key.next().charAt(0);

        if (yesno == 'Y'){
            /*affirmative response*/
            System.out.println("Okay, here it comes!");
        }
        else{
            /*negative response*/
            System.out.println("What a wimp...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        /*Quiz Section*/

        /*Question 1*/
        System.out.println("Q1)  What is the capital of Alaska?");
        System.out.println("         1)  Melbourne\n" +
                         "         2)  Anchorage\n" +
                         "         3)  Juneau");
        answer = key.nextInt();

        if (answer == 3){
            System.out.println("\nCorrect!!!");
            /*store to function stating number of correct answers*/
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\nWrong.");
        }

        /*Question 2*/
        System.out.println("Q2)  Can you store the value 'cat' in a variable of type int?");
        System.out.println("         1)  yes\n" +
                           "         2)  no");
        answer = key.nextInt();

        if (answer == 2){
            System.out.println("\nCorrect!!!");
            /*store to function stating number of correct answers*/
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\nWrong.");
        }

        /*Question 3*/
        System.out.println("Q3)  What is the result of 9+6/3?");
        System.out.println("         1)  5\n" +
                           "         2)  11\n" +
                           "         3)  15/3");
        answer = key.nextInt();

        if (answer == 2){
            System.out.println("\nCorrect!!!");
            /*store to function stating number of correct answers*/
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\nWrong.");
        }

        /*Wrapping Up*/
        System.out.println("Overall, you got " + correctOutOf() + " out of 3 correct.");
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    }

    /*not sure of which access modifier to use, but none have fixed it*/
    private static int correctOutOf(int answer) {
       return corrAns;
    }
}
```

I'm feeling pretty positive that my if statement is going to feed the 'correctOutOf' method simply because it is the only part of the statement that can check for a correct answer with the code as-is.  (just so everyone knows my train of thought.)

Edit - if this is something more than a beginner should be messing with, thanks for pointing it out. (Biting off more than I can chew?)

Comment: How many parameter does your `correctOutOf` method declare?

Comment: `int answer` is the only one I think I'll need.  I tried passing the variable `int answer` as a last resort with no positive results

Comment: It expects one parameter, great. Now how many arguments are you passing in your invocation, `correctOutOf() `?

Comment: not sure...  Complete noob, but how about - 

`int result = answer++;`

Comment: Use two more variables one for totalQuestions and one for correctAnswerCount. On asking question increment totalQuestions and on correct answers increment correcTAnswerCount. Modify coorectOutOf method and pass these two varables to it.

Comment: unclear???  @Aaron Franke had no problem figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that, do this at the start of main:

```
byte correct = 0;
```

Or this if you ever need to use it outside of main:

```
private static byte correct = 0;
```

Then add this to each correct answer if statement:

```
correct++;
```

And print the variable "correct".

...also, you may wish to add this function to your program, to replace "key.nextInt()", to prevent the user from crashing your program:

```
import java.util.regex.*; 

private static final int integer() {
    boolean invalid = true; 
    int number = 0; 
    while (invalid) { 
        String input = key.next(); 
        if (input.matches("\\d+")){ 
            invalid = false; 
            try { 
                number = Int.parseInt(input); 
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) { 
                invalid = true; 
                System.out.print("Are you trying to break the program? Try again: "); 
            } 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("That's not a whole number! "); 
            System.out.print("Try again: "); 
        } 
    } 
    return number; 
}
```

Comment: thanks aaron.  I just figured out the basics of iterations?  Maybe?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. This code is quite linear with no loops whatsoever. Aside from maybe repeating the same line of code a few times, there's not much iterating in here.

Comment: `++`?  Nevermind.  I'm really just starting out other than simply tinkering for the last 2-3 years.

increment/decrement is the word/s I thought I was using.

Comment: The ++ function just adds one. It's the same as "correct += 1;" or "correct = correct + 1;"

Comment: reputation is below 15 or I would.  I'll come back to it when I can do so :)